How to access the previous state and current state inside a selector in ngrx selectors?
I'm wondering if it's possible to access both the previous and current state in ngrx selectors. I haven't been able to find relevant information about this. Is it because I'm using createSelector? Is there a factory method available for this? My goal is to access both the current and previous state and perform some operations to derive data.
If it's possible, please share some examples.
Thanks in advance!

Try pairwise
  store.pipe(select(<selector>)
    startWith({ oldValue: null, newValue: null }),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    pairwise(),
    map(([oldValue, newValue]) => { return { oldValue, newValue } })
  )
  .subscribe({
      next: (val) => {
          console.log(val)
      }
  });

